# Update with a for / foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops, for-loop

I am having some problems with updating a part of my script.

I have a webpage wher users can mark checkboxes next to each user they want to 'recycle' with another use.

I store the users id in an array like this:

```
$refsid= explode(',',$_POST['referralIds']); 
$users->_recycleMulti($membershipData['recycle_price'], $userdata['username'], $refsid);
```

Then, in my `_recycleMulti` function, I wish to do the actual recycling. Whether it is just one user that have been selected, or 10. Therefore, I am using a `for loop.`

Yet it still only just updates **one** user.

My _recycleMulti function looks like this:

```
function _recycleMulti($value, $username, $referrals_array){


        for($i=0; $i < count($referrals_array); $i++){

            mysql_query("do the update here");

        }
        return "success!"; 

    }
```

`var_dump($_POST['referralIds']);` is returning:

```
string(3) "4,5"
```

This is correct, as I have checked two checkboxes. The ids match the ones in the database.

```
var_dump($refsid);  is returning:

array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "4" [1]=> string(1) "5" }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you add the HTML for the referralIds, please? You might want to add in `var_dump($refsid)` and `var_dump($_POST['referralIds'])`, too, to make sure that they contain what you think they contain.

Comment: I have updated my question with the info from var_dump

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: How do you figure that it only updates one user? From the data in the database after you ran the script? Can you add output inside the loop to see what it's doing there? Can you give details on the query you're executing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the for loop to a foreach though it should not make a difference in the execution

```
foreach ($referrals_array as $refid) {
    echo "Updating referral ".$refid.".<br>\n";
    // execute SQL code here using $refid value
}
```

that might help you see what you're executing, or if that's not working well enough, echo your SQL statement and make sure it's doing what you think it is.

Comment: This actually worked. It updated each id. No idea why the 'for' loop didn't.

Thanks!